# Wyse ThinOS MirrorFileServer Setting (FW 8.3 - 8.5)

Tags: thin-client, wyse

I have a support ticket open with Dell, at the moment they're saying they're unable to reproduce the issue. I'm hoping someone else with a Wyse environment can test and provide some feedback.

It appears to me that the MirrorFileServer parameter has been broken since 8.3_012. Starting with 8.3_012 the MirrorFileServer parameter appears to force the thin client to run off the cached wnos.ini file, changes made on the FTP server are therefore ignored.

This can be tested as shown.

- Perform Factory Reset
- Set TCP Timeout to 2 x 30
- Set Static IP, Subnet Mask, and Gateway
- Set FTP Server
- Restart thin client
- Check terminal name (should be TC001)
- Change terminal name on FTP Server
- Restart thin client
- Check terminal name (should be TC002)

**wnos.ini**

```
MirrorFileServer=yes

Terminalname=TC001
;Terminalname=TC002
DNSIPVersion=ipv4 DNSServer=1.1.1.1;1.1.1.2 DNSDomain=fqdn
SignOn=No
```

I have tested 8.3_012, 8.3_014, 8.3_109, 8.4_105, 8.4_112, 8.5_009, and 8.5_012. None of them work as expected, after the 2nd restart the terminal name is still TC001. 8.2 and older do work as expected, the wnos.ini file is downloaded from the FTP server and the terminal name is changed to TC002.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting with 8.3 I have found I need to add the following to my configuration.

**wnos.ini**

```
WDMService=No Discover=No
CCMEnable=No Discover=No
```

My assumption is in a FTP only environment, WDM and CCM are taking too long to timeout and are interrupting the FTP download.